# Does scalamock support mocking curried mehtod that has implicit and repeated parameters?

Tags: scalamock

I need to mock following method using scalamock, but I didn't manage to do it. It is curried, has implicit and repeated parameters in the same time. 
Does scalamock library support mocking such combination?

```
def apply(key: String, args: Any*)(implicit lang: Lang): String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
"complicated paramter lists" should "be mockable" in {
  trait Foo {
    def apply(key: String, args: Any*)(implicit lang: String): String
  }

  val m = mock[Foo]
  (m.apply(_: String, _: Seq[Any])(_: String)) expects(*, *, *) returning "Foo" once()


  implicit val s = "foo"
  m.apply("bar", 5, true, 42.0) should be ("Foo")
}
```